# How do I use cfoauth for Microsoft Single Sign On or with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, coldfusion, single-sign-on

I'm trying to set up an internal website so that my company's users can log in without creating brand new accounts. **I am open to using Microsoft Single Sign On OR pulling from our Active Directory on Azure.**

I have been over every [piece of documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfoauth.html) so many times it's starting to all look the same.

`cfoauth` only implicitly supports Facebook and Google login types. Incidentally, I got those to work very easily, so it was very encouraging. But for every other `type`, you must enter some combination of accesstoken and endpoint. A Microsoft entry might look something like:

```
<cflogin>
<cfoauth
accesstoken="???"
endpoint="???"
clientid = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
secretkey = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
result = "res"
redirecturi = "http://localhost:8500/doc/login.cfm" >
<cfloginuser name = "#res.other.username#" password = "#res.access_token#" roles = "user"/>
</cflogin>
<cflocation url="http://localhost:8500/doc/index.cfm" >
```

Or would it? I have no idea! I've already registered the web app on Azure. It has a Client ID and a Secret Key. Everything I've tried does... nothing. No 500 errors, and ColdFusion isn't even trying to hit Azure. I don't believe I even have the right syntax.

I have been across the internet and not one single working example of this exists. I found a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/oauth2) that looks very promising, but everything bleeds together and I honestly am so fried I can't tell where I'm supposed to plug any of my variables in.

StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. But someone, please, give me a hint.

How do I let users login to this website with Single Sign On?

I'm using ColdFusion 2018. IIS 10. Windows Server 2019.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test the repo right now, but it does look very thorough and uses direct http calls instead of the `<cfoauth>` tag. Strictly from reviewing the links posted ... it sounds like the docs are saying "we created shortcuts for the common "type"(s) google and facebook so you can just enter `type=google` or `type=facebook`. For any other providers you must supply the tag with 2 urls: one for "accesstoken" and another for the "endpoint".  Looking at the test cases, the `microsoft.cfc` init() function shows those url's:

Comment: `string authEndpoint = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf'` and ... `string accessTokenEndpoint = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf'`

Comment: Since this is company-internal, are they already authenticated to be on your network? You mentioned Active Directory, so I imagine so. You can work with LDAP to auth them to your CF app. I don't know that I'd recommend having a company intranet site logging in with credentials that you can't fully control. Plus the security implications can be pretty wide with SSO. If something happens (like, say, Facebook logins get breached) then anyone with access to those accounts has access to your system. So if you go with OAuth, also think of a way to quickly mass revoke access if needed. :-(

Comment: That's a good point @Shawn.

Comment: @Ageax It's a sad world we live in. This stuff would be so much easier if everyone were nice. :-)  The drawback to trusting someone else to tell you if your user is trustworthy is that you still trust your users until you find out your original source is lying to you. And unfortunately if you are relying on a big target like Google or Facebook, you have to make sure to monitor them so that a major breach doesn't pass you by.

Comment: @Ageax I knew I was missing something with the `authEndPoint` and `accessTokenEndpoint` attributes. They're named differently in documentation and I was ping ponging this stuff in my brain all day yesterday to the point that it just stopped making sense. Thanks for setting me straight. I was able to get it to fire, the only error was something on my end in regards to App Registration. If you want to flesh out your comment as an answer, the points are yours.